# How would I structure a kubectl-like CLI with python-click?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, python-click

I would like to create a CLI that receives an action and resource parameters to work, in a `kubectl` fashion. Eg.

```
myctl init config
myctl create issue|pr|branch
myctl delete issue|pr|branch|config
```

myctl command should always receive 2 arguments, so that the user wouldn't try something like: `myctl init config delete issue`. Also the should not be able to execute impossible combinations such as `myctl create config`.

I though of some code like:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.group()
@click.option(
    "init,create,delete",
    type=str,
    help="Action name.",
)
@click.option(
    "config,issue,pr,branch",
    type=str,
    help="Resource name.",
)
def main(action: str, resource: str) -> None:
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(prog_name="myctl")
```

I am not really sure what click elements should I use in order to structure that (arguments, options, groups, etc) and how to put that together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've achieved this in the past by creating multiple nested groups.

```py
import click


@click.group('cli')
def cli():
    pass


@click.group('init')
def init():
    pass


@click.group('create')
def create():
    pass


@click.group('delete')
def delete():
    pass


@init.command('config')
def config():
    print('Configuration complete')


@create.command('issue')
@click.argument('name')
def issue(name):
    print(f'Created {name}')


@create.command('pr')
@click.argument('base_branch', required=False, default='master')
def pr(base_branch):
    print(f'Created PR against {base_branch}')


@create.command('branch')
@click.argument('name')
def branch(name):
    print(f'Create branch {name}')


@delete.command('issue')
@click.argument('issue_number')
def delete_issue(issue_number):
    print(f'Deleting issue {issue_number}')


@delete.command('pr')
@click.argument('pr_number')
def delete_pr(pr_number):
    print(f'Deleting PR {pr_number}')


@delete.command('branch')
@click.argument('branch_name')
def delete_branch(branch_name):
    print(f'Deleting branch {branch_name}')


@delete.command('config')
@click.argument('config_name')
def delete_config(config_name):
    print(f'Deleting config {config_name}')


cli.add_command(init)
cli.add_command(create)
cli.add_command(delete)


def run_cli():
    cli()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_cli()
```

You can then expand this however you want, with invocations looking like the following. I've called my CLI `play`.

```
❯ play
Usage: play [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  create
  delete
  init

❯ play init
Usage: play init [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  config

❯ play init config
Configuration complete

❯ play create
Usage: play create [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  branch
  issue
  pr

❯ play create branch feature/the-coolest
Create branch feature/the-coolest
```

You can then proceed to add short help messages and customise it to your application.

Comment: P.S. If you're looking for a particular CLI utility tool for Git, rather than just a learning exercise, there are a few very good ones available, offering some really useful features

Comment: Cool @afterburner, thanks. BTW, which git CLI utilities do you recommend?

Comment: I've been really happy with hub, for the most part. I ended up developing my own because I needed something more, to cope with work (think cloning hundreds of repos with one command). I know hub's no longer being developed in favour of the official Git CLI, and that one's cool, but it's a work in progress

https://github.com/github/hub
https://github.com/cli/cli

Comment: I took a look on these ones, and I am creating my own also to manage multiple projects at the same time. I also use Github Enterprise and Gitlab. So they don't help me.

Comment: Hub works with GHE. I haven't looked into Gitlab and I don't know if its API differs from Github's. But if the sort of thing you're after is cloning out multiple repositories, seeing PRs across multiple repos, raising PRs, checking out a new branch in multiple repos for cross repo contributions, I can open source mine in a day or two, and it's not a blank slate you're starting with

Comment: I've already developed the API calls, the only part missing was creating commands, but maybe we can merge together what we've developed. Check out my repo: github.com/staticdev/git-portfolio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216902/discussion-between-afterburner-and-staticdev).